# помогите определиться с методом генерации изображения

Tags: php, javascript, canvas, gd, imagick

добрый день.
есть задача наложения одного изображения на другое, при этом верхнее изображение подвергается трансформации (масштабируется и позиционируется). Вариаций изображений довольно много поэтому не очень бы хотелось все эти вариации создавать изначально и хранить на сервере. Более рационально как по мне, то генерация на лету.  Всего скажем генерируется около 15 изображений (т.е. есть 15 фонов и на них накладываются определенные изображения соответствующие каждому товару, а таких изображений у товара может быть до 20 шт., итого для 1го товара 20*15=300 шт. Т.е. очевидно что не очень выгодно их хранить ).

Изображения генерируются не только при открытии страницы товара, но и при выборе разных опций, т.е. кол-во запросов на генерацию может быть сколь угодно большим даже на одной странице (есть же кто хочет поклацать :) ).

Хотел у опытных в данном вопросе поинтересоваться какой лучше метод выбрать: генерации на сервере или в браузере, а именно:

1) Если на сервере:
  - генерация с использованием imagick/gd и отдача в виде инлайн base64 кода.
  - создавать в виде кеша, который потом будет очищаться (тут не до конца понимаю как это реализовывается. Т.е. происходит проверка на существование и если нет то перегенерация?)
  - какой то еще серверный способ?

2) либо же в браузере:
  - наложением дивов и трансформацией/позиционированием стилями (на сколько надежно в плане адаптивности?)
  - с использованием canvas
  - может еще какой то вариант?

Всего если генерить на сервере то передается около 1,5 мб каждый раз, но вопрос не столько трафика, сколько нагрузки на сервер каждой такой генерацией скриптом. не будет ли сильно это садить ресурсы?
Вообщем посоветуйте плиз как лучше поступить в данном случае?

Answer (score 0):

То что вы хотите, "генерировать на лету" ваш сервер "ляжет" точно "ляжет".
По мне лучше генерировать в начале, при добавление товара или cron-ном.
Если нет изображения, не генерировать, а отдавать "заглушку"

Так как для поисковиков, да и для пользователей важно скорость, при "генерации на лету", время будет уходит более 1 сек, иногда и больше

Из `imagick/gd` особо разницы нет, смотря если `imagick` если да, то он, удобнее

Comment: в том то и дело что не хочется хранить такое кол-во изображений на сервере.

Comment: @myrecs Тогда вам нужно будет взять более мощный сервер, хотя по мне хранить изображения, куда выгоднее чем из за этого тратится на мощный сервер